# Can I write a validation rule to make a field enabled or disabled based on picklist value?

Tags: validation, validation-rule, conditional

**Note: in standard page layout**

is it possible to write a validation rule to make a field enabled or disabled based on picklist value?

i have a picklist - values

```
             cycle - monthly
                     quaterly
                     semi annual
                     annual
                     other
```

if picklist value is other a text field **days** has to be enabled

how can i achieve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the validation rule to make sure that the record cannot be saved unless the Days text field is filled in if the picklist value is 'other'.

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Cycle__c, "other"),
    ISBLANK(Days__c)
)
```

This will give the user an error if they try to save a record where the picklist value os other and the days field is left blank.

You cannot though control whether or not the days field is enabled though.  You would need a visualforce page to accomplish this functionality.

Comment: In addition to that, you would also need the reverse validation rule to block off users filling in Days__c when Cycle__c is not "Other", thus effectively disabling the field.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to SFDC_NINJA answer you can also show and hide the days field with field dependency feature.

Comment: This is not possible with a text field though, which is what Days__c seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying to a very old thread, but if people are still wanting Salesforce to add this feature, please upvote the idea in the Success Community. 10 points / vote.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kzVyAAI